# Stop Go server when browser is closed

Tags: go, server

I'm running a simple Go server on a OSX machine. When I run the command to run the Go program it starts the server and open a browser window.

I would like to know if there's a way to when I close that browser window (by the window, not the program) also close the server and quit the terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could let your browser emit a message before dying, or use a web socket, but a simple, reliable and usual way to do that kind of stuff is to set up a Javascript timer to have the browser send a heart-beat message to the server every now and then (depending on how quickly you want the server to stop after the browser's closing ; every second, every 15s, every minute... ?). When the server figures that a due message has not arrived, it can exit.

Comment: you can also open a websocket connection and wait for it to die.
you will get an immediate timeout.  Which, you could also (effectively) do by setting the above timer to trigger every 500ms or something.  (timer approach is easier in that you don't require 3rd party libs)